# Highcharts server side image generation, how to set up legend labelFormatter in callback argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts, phantomjs

I'am working on a PDF file generator that user Highcharts server side image generation to populate graph information in the document.

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/render-charts-serverside

Everything work great and i would customize my highchart legend to get one legend per line at the bottom of the graph.
Because the server side generation use JSON format, i could not set the "legend.labelFormatter" callback to force break line after each legend.

There is a simple exemple in the readme of source code, but I can not fit my needs. (https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/exporting-server/phantomjs)

The readme exemple :

```
function(chart) {
    chart.renderer.arc(200, 150, 100, 50, -Math.PI, 0).attr({
        fill : '#FCFFC5',
        stroke : 'black',
        'stroke-width' : 1
     }).add();
}
```

My own callback

```
function(chart){

    console.log('COOL!');

    chart.legend.labelFormatter = function () {


        console.log('COOL 2!');


        return this.name + "\n";
    };

    chart.redraw();

}
```

Comment: of course, that never goes to display "COOL 2!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two solutions (at least) to get what you need:

- <s>use `labelFormat` instead of `labelFormatter`, see [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.labelFormat). In your case: `labelFormat: "{name}\n"`</s> - won't work
- render legend as vertical, using `layout` options. Again, see [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.layout).
- set fixed `width` for the legend, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m6ot1v8f/1/).

Anyway, have you tried to use `labelFormatter`? I know it's JSON, but I think it works.

Comment: To send charts options, i have to post data to a PHP webservice. Before sending options, i use in JS JSON.stringify that remove all object typed "callback". I tried it first and it's how i learn that JSON format does not contain callback :-/
I'll try with labelformat. About the vertical layout, another problem occured. The calcul of chart height with legend is a little bit difficult to do  not show the legend navigation when i'm generating image. With the horizontal layout, this facilitated by a highcharts plugin (https://github.com/highslide-software/adapt-chart-to-legend).

Comment: Well, i tried 'labelFormat: "{name}\n"' but that does not work. And finally i tried to set layout to vertical and it was working at first time as i would.

Comment: Indeed, `pointFormat` won't work. Another solution is to set `width` for the legend, so chart will wrap legend items, example: http://jsfiddle.net/m6ot1v8f/1/

Comment: And regarding JSON - indeed, JSON doesn't support functions. However, when testing [exporting](http://export.highcharts.com) with labelFormatter - it works. I think you don't need to use `JSON.stringify()`.